# I/O of File in C++

Tags: c++, io

im trying to create a C++ program that reads a file and counts the number of lines, words and characters in the file following specific guidelines:

- Uses std::getline() to read the input line by line.
- counts all characters including the newline characters that separate lines. The return value of     cin.eof() can be used to determine whether a line was terminated by a newline character or not.
- Each word is separated by a space or tab ("\t").
- first_of() and first_not_of() to find the beginning of the next word.

The only problem is that i have no idea how to do this. I did however, manage to count the number of lines using the getline(). But after that, no idea. If you could point me to the right direction and show me how to do this (im a visual learner) i would greatly appreciate it!

Heres what i got so far (not much i know):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    int numLines = 0; 
    ifstream file ("horton.txt");
    if (file.is_open()){
        while ( getline (file,line) ){
            ++numLines;
        }
    file.close();
    cout <<numLines<<endl;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
}
```

Comment: Anyone? Please i need some help here as im drawing blanks.

Comment: So, how would you know if a string contains a character such as space or tab?

Comment: for this assignment, assume there is.

Comment: No, I'm asking you how you would write code to "know" that...

Comment: If you dont know how to do it efficiently, try first the simplest way possible.
For example, after reading a line to the variable `line`, you could, for example, count the occurrences of tabs and space. This way, you will know the number of words. And why not, while checking the characters keep a variable counting them. Afterwards you may think a way to handle weird situations (if it happens in the file).. like space/tab followed by other space/tab... etc. Try solving one problem at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's remove the file from the scenario and work with searching for words in a known sentence.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio>

int main(void)
{
  const std::string test_data = "I do not like green eggs and ham, Sam I am.";

  return 0;
}
```

According to your requirements, the `std::string::find_first_of` can be used to find words.  Let's add a string containing the word separators and call it `white_space`:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio>

int main(void)
{
  const std::string test_data = "I do not like green eggs and ham, Sam I am.";
  const std::string white_space = " \t"; // Space and tab.

  return 0;
}
```

We can search the `test_data` for the first occurrence of a white space:

```
std::string::size_t position = test_data.find_first_of(white_space);
```

This statement will set the variable `position` to the position of the first white space character in the text string.  In our example, it should be 1, as the letter 'I' occupies position 0.

With a little bit more thought, we could increment the position past the space and use the `find_first_not_of` method to get the position of the next space.  If we save the previous position, we can extract the word we just skipped over.

You may be able to get away with count the number of white space instances.

By using a debugger, we single step (execute) one statement at a time and see how the `position` variable changes within a loop.  If you have an objection to debuggers, you use the ancient art of printing variable names and their values to the console.

Comment: ok, how would i make find_first_of start from the last position find_first_not_of set it to? Also, how would i check if the line is finished and if the line is simply blank (no characters)?

Comment: I dunno, probably by looking at my language text or cppreference.com and noticing that the std::string method `find_first_not_of` has an optional parameter for the starting position.  Ooooh, there are soooo many ways to detect an empty string:  `(test_data.length() == 0), (test_data.size() == 0), (test_data.empty())`.  There's sooo much you can find out by reading the reference manual.

Comment: I've heard there is a value that these search functions return when they reach or go beyond the end of the string.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos